# How to add a *.P12 keystore (with one entry)?

Tags: https, java-8, certificate, pkcs#12

Apologies for my lack of understanding of certificates in general.  I have a `.p12` file (with a non-expired certificate) and a valid password so I can `list` the contents using:

```
keytool -list -keystore file.p12 -storepass password -storetype PKCS12 -v
```

In my Java code I am attempting an HTTPS post but keep getting this error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching [host.path.com] found
```

This same post works against one of my other environments which does not have any authentication required and the link is HTTP (vs. HTTPS).  How do I make this `.p12` file work for it to be recognized in the handshake?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following command

```
keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore alice.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore "c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_71\lib\security\cacerts"  -deststoretype JKS
```

Default password for your cacerts will be **changeit**

Where trust store will be your JRE trust store

Please refer here for more information 
http://www.webfarmr.eu/2010/04/import-pkcs12-private-keys-into-jks-keystores-using-java-keytool/

Comment: I'm in `jdk1.8xxx\jre\lib\security\ ` (and I copied the .p12 file in also), but I don't see a `truststore.jks` file.  I tried the command but am getting a FileNotFoundException, am I supposed to replace truststore with another filename?