# Which certificates must I put on the keystore and the truststore of Java?

Tags: java, keystore, truststore, pkcs#12

I want to call a webservice with Java that needs mutual SSL authentication.

This web service is accessible over a secure and authenticated connection, both on the server side and the client side.

I have a PKCS12 file (.p12) provided to make the authenticated connection, this file contains 4 entries:

- TEST _ CAIH Timestamp (Private RSA Key).
- TEST _ CAIH Timestamp (Verified by: XX - Easy CA).
- XX - Easy CA (Verified by: XX - Root CA).
- XX - Root CA (Verified by: XX - Root CA).

Which certificates or/and keys  of the P12 file must I put on the keystore and the truststore ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Those entries are not all clear to me, however, the basic rule to remember is that `keystore=who we are` and `truststore=who we trust`

Comment: Also, have a look on that, it's probably a similar issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778525/how-to-add-a-p12-keystore-with-one-entry